# Converting java code to c#

Tags: java, c#, android, windows-phone-8, porting

I am making a porting of this code from java(Android) to C#(Windows Phone) but i have no idea how to do that, here is the code that i'm trying do convert:

```
  private void executeSingleOperation() {

        operation.execute(new OperationResult() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                //do something
                this.executeSingleOperation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(Error err) {
                //andle the error
            }
    });
}
```

OperationResult is an interface and looks like this:

```
public interface OperationResult {

    public void onSuccess(Object obj);

    public void onFail(Error err); }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no equivalent to anonymous inner classes in C#. For single-method versions, you can often use delegates instead of interfaces, then use lambda expressions (or just regular methods) to specify an implementation.

Otherwise, just use a regular class to implement the interface.

In this case, you *might* want to mix the two, having an implementation of the interface which itself takes two delegates in the constructor - one for failure and one for success. It really depends on the context, and we don't have a lot of that at the moment.

I would say that if you're fairly new to C#, you'd be better off investigating it in the context of a console app as a *much* simpler environment for experimentation.

Comment: Can you post an example i'm really confused, i'm new on c#

Comment: @frenk91: It's not clear what's confusing you. It sounds like you should probably read a tutorial on interfaces, and maybe another on delegates.